# How to query list of all directories with images in it, efficiently?

Tags: android, gallery, mediastore, bucket

I need to query MediaStore and get all the bucket names as a list. It is easy to do it and there is tons of questions with answer on stackoverflow however all of the answers are having one big efficiency problem. They all query all of the images to get a list of gallery. So if there is thousands of images in 10 directories, it takes too much time to query those only 10 directory names. I want to know if there is any better way to query those list of directories without querying all of the images.

Answer (score 0):

Battle-tested code:

```
public void collectPhotosInFolder(File directory, boolean recurse, List<File> list) {
    Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Reading photos in file system folder " + directory.getAbsolutePath());

    File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            String name = file.getName();
            if (name.contains(".")) {
                String ext = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);                 
                return ((ext.compareToIgnoreCase("jpg") == 0) || (ext.compareToIgnoreCase("jpeg") == 0) || (ext.compareToIgnoreCase("png") == 0));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (files == null)
        files = new File[0];

    for (File file : files)
        list.add(file);

    if (recurse) {
        File[] dirs = directory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.isDirectory();
            }
        });

        for (File dir : dirs)
            collectPhotosInFolder(dir, recurse, list);
    }
}
```